# Using a name from an existing list, to create a new list but also using that name as the name of the new list

Tags: r, parsing, string-concatenation

I have written a code but need to write it a different way.
Here is some example code to create two lists

```
set.seed(123)    # sets random seed
height <- sample(120:200,200,TRUE) # create random height data 
vars <- c("height") # create a list which contains 'height'
```

I know i can run these two lines below to get the same results

```
mean(height) # the straightforward way to calculate mean
mean(eval(parse(text = vars[1]))) # using the name from the list
[1] 160.49
```

I then want to create a new list **mean_height** that contains a value, I've included straightforward way to show example what I'm trying to do in it's most basic form. The second line I'm using a "mean_" concatenated with "height" from list

```
mean_height <- mean(height) # the straightforward way create list containing mean score
assign(paste("mean_", vars[1], sep = ""), mean(eval(parse(text = vars[1]))))  # using the name from the list
mean_height
[1] 160.49
```

This code works but I can't integrate with something else I'm trying to write. 
I would like to create **mean_height** in the manner below but it won't run

```
paste("mean_", vars[1], sep = "") <- mean(eval(parse(text = vars[1])))
```

I get this error message

```
Error in paste("mean_", vars[1], sep = "") <- mean(eval(parse(text = vars[1]))) : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

Is there a function I can use to put around **paste("mean_", vars[1], sep = "")** to get it recognised?

Any help, is much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to work with variable names as character values, you can use `get()` and `assign()` (avoid using `eval(parse())`). But in general it's much easier and more R-like to work with related in named lists rather than using separate variables. Also you can use `paste0()` rather than `paste(..., sep="")`. In your case `assign(paste0("mean_", vars[1]), mean(get(vars[1])))` should work. I'm not sure what the "something else" would be that this won't integrate with.

Comment: I agree with MrFlick, but if you feel like you _have_ to extract the variables to the global environment, there is `list2env`: `mh <- lapply(vars, function(x) mean(get(x))); names(mh) <- paste0("mean_",vars); list2env(mh , envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. I've only started using R (I'm only just making the transition from the old world of SAS/SPSS). Hence why my questions probably don't make much sense at the moment till i get used to R. I am learning to be more R-like. Thanks for the advice i will look up the functions you recommended.